# inserting characters in footnotes, in Indesign

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

when i select some text then run the code below, i can replace the two characters right before and after that selected text, but this code doesn't work if i select the text in footnotes.. how can i make it work there also?

```
var myStory = app.selection[0].parentStory;
var myIndex = app.selection[0].index;
var myInS = app.selection[0].insertionPoints[0].index;

var toplam = app.selection[0].characters.length
var toplama = app.selection[0].insertionPoints.length;

var myText1 = myStory.characters[myIndex-1];
var myText2 = myStory.characters[myIndex+toplam+0];

myText1.contents = "\uFD3F";  
myText2.contents = "\uFD3E";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it using straight way:

```
    app.selection[0].insertionPoints[-1].contents = "\uFD3E";
    app.selection[0].insertionPoints[0].contents = "\uFD3F";
```

In case of replacing:

```
    var 
    myParent = app.selection[0].parent,
    char1 = myParent.characters[app.selection[0].characters[0].index - 1],
    char2 = myParent.characters[app.selection[0].characters[-1].index + 1];

    char2.contents = "\uFD3E";
    char1.contents = "\uFD3F";
```

It assumes selection is somewhere inbetween any characters (and is not just an insertionPoint...)

Jarek

Comment: thank you; but I think I forgot to mention that I try to **replace** the two characters right before and after selected text.. What would be the straight way of doing that?